# Codeigniter pagination segment 4

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

My url is http://example.com/app/index.php/app/view/11/, so the idea is that i am already on a product page which get data from segment(3) in url(11), now each product may have some records in a table, i need pagination for those records.

The code i tried is:

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/feedapp/index.php/app/view/' . $this->uri->segment(3) . '/';
```

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

if the codeigniter folder is 'feedapp' and your controller is 'app' and the method is 'view'

```
 function view($id) {

       $this->load->library( 'pagination' );
       $config = array();
       $config['base_url'] = site_url( "app/view/$id" );

       // etc etc etc 

}
```

Comment: then post all of your code and the error message you get.